# Time Machine error code 21 and 19, "Failed to mount.... because the image could not be attached"

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

With macOS sierra (10.12.4), Time Machine backups to a Synology NAS are failing in the "preparing backup" phase. The UI messages aren't helpful, but console shows this error from backupd:

```
Failed to mount '/Volumes/TimeMachine/fubar.sparsebundle'
because the image could not be attached, error:
Error Domain=com.apple.backupd.ErrorDomain Code=21 "(null)"
UserInfo={MessageParameters=(
    "/Volumes/TimeMachine/fubar.sparsebundle",
    19
)}
```

This repeats every 60 seconds for several minutes, and then Time Machine gives up.

I'm familiar with the sort of problem fixed by https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39842/30668 but this seems to be different. I can mount the network volume and attach the sparsebundle. Running fsck shows no errors. The sparsebundle plist shows `VerificationState` 0, and doesn't have a `RecoveryBackupDeclinedDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a keychain problem. Possibly I changed the NAS login password and never updated keychain.

1. Settings > Time Machine > Stop using "TimeMachine" for Backup
2. Keychain > search for NAS hostname and delete all matching passwords. I think the problem entries were in the System keychain, but I also deleted entries from the login keychain.
3. Settings > Time Machine > Add Backup Disk... > select "TimeMachine" > enter password

This situation was confusing because the messages from Time Machine didn't say anything about authentication, and Finder could connect to the NAS volume ok. But apparently backupd uses a different Keychain entry, which was bad or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be that the Time Machine user account accessing the NAS had exceeded its quota from usage elsewhere in the volume (facepalm).

This ended up causing the `Info.plist` file inside the sparsebundle to be 0 bytes. Fortunately there was an `Info.bckup` file in there that I copied over to be the new `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (error 21) it was a garbled `Info.plist` file[1] (on Time Capsule). Fortunately there was a backup file called `Info.bckup` which I used to replace the garbled one. Which solved my problem.

---

[1] Don't ask me how that stuff got into the `Info.plist` file...:

`$ more Info.plist
an Loop[2]   : 50
Skin Side 3 Fan Loop[3]   : 50
Skin Side 3 Fan Loop[4]   : 0 0 44 271 47 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Skin Side 4 Fan Loop[0]   : 50
Skin Side 4 Fan Loop[1]   : 38912
Skin Side 4 Fan Loop[2]   : 50
Skin Side 4 Fan Loop[3]   : 50
Skin Side 4 Fan Loop[4]   : 164 198 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
HDD Radio Loop[0]         : 100
HDD Radio Loop[1]         : 102400
HDD Radio Loop[2]         : 100
HDD Radio Loop[3]         : 100
HDD Radio Loop[4]         : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 362
2G Radio Radio`