# Time Machine backup fails returning 112 and other errors

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule, error

I've encountered 112 error when attempting to back via Time Machine to Time Capsule:

[image: 112 error]
 I've tried:

- Restarts, both Mac and Time Capsule
- Running *Verify Backups* available via Time Machine menu when holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Returns the following error:
  [image: verification error]
- Trying to inherit this backup again, what failed with the following error:

  ```
  20:36 $ sudo tmutil inheritbackup "/Volumes/TimeCapsuleData/Konrad-Mac.sparsebundle"
  Attaching disk image...
  ** /dev/rdisk2s2 (NO WRITE)
  Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
  QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM CLEAN
  /Volumes/TimeCapsuleData/Konrad-Mac.sparsebundle: Attach failed: Failed to attach disk image. (error 112)
  ```
- Trying to mount this disk image, which fails with the following error message:
  [image: mount fail]

Is there anything else that I can try to make this backup work?

---

## Updates

### Logs

*sourced via:*

```
log show --style syslog  --predicate 'senderImagePath contains[cd] "TimeMachine"' --info
```

*Log:*

```
2018-06-20 19:35:26.694387+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Starting manual backup
2018-06-20 19:35:26.710775+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Attempting to mount network destination URL: afp://Konrad;AUTH=SRP@TimeCapsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local./TimeCapsuleData
2018-06-20 19:35:40.516852+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Mounted network destination at mount point: /Volumes/TimeCapsuleData using URL: afp://Konrad;AUTH=SRP@TimeCapsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local./TimeCapsuleData
2018-06-20 19:35:41.290423+0100  localhost backupd-helper[92]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Re-scheduled next backup in 60 to 90 minutes
2018-06-20 19:36:00.825991+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Checking for runtime corruption on /dev/disk2s2
2018-06-20 19:37:11.508689+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to mount disk image: Error Domain=com.apple.backupd.ErrorDomain Code=21 "(null)" UserInfo={MessageParameters=(
    "/Volumes/TimeCapsuleData/Konrad-Mac.sparsebundle",
    112
)}
2018-06-20 19:37:13.480113+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Ejected Time Machine network volume.
2018-06-20 19:37:13.481428+0100  localhost backupd[7817]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Waiting 60 seconds and trying again.
```

### Repair attempt

Following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39842/98828), I've tried running:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/disk2s2
```

which returned the following:

```
22:29 $ sudo fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/disk2s2
journal_replay(/dev/disk2s2) returned 0
** /dev/rdisk2s2
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=65536 cacheSize=2097152K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
    could not get volume block 2, err 5
    could not get alternate volume header at 5855666958, err 5
volumeType is 0
0000:  0060 6113 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |..a.............|
0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
    unknown volume type
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00
    sector size = 512 0x200
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01
    total sectors for volume = 5855666960 0x15d066310
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
    CheckForClean - unknown volume type
    CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0
```

Comment: Does the air come up directly after starting a back up or does it happen after a little while?

Comment: How is the disk connected to the machine you're backing up?

Comment: @Scottmeup I've `AirPort Time Capsule 802.11n (4th Generation)` so the connection is over WiFi.

Comment: @Josh After *preparing backup* it seems to be failing when attempting to back up

Comment: Can you paste logs?

Comment: @Josh I added one bit, it goes on a loop later on.