# How do I repair a Time Machine Sparsebundle that will not mount or attach?

Tags: terminal, time-machine, mount, sparsebundle

My wife's Laptop died.  Her backup was on a Synology NAS and we need to get at some files from the backup by accessing the Sparsebundle from another Mac.

I made a copy of the Sparsebundle to work on from the other Mac but can't mount it.  I've searched the internet for ways to repair it, but can't get by the step where you "attach" it in a terminal command.  I found a script called TimeMachineRepairScript.sh that is supposed to do all the right things, such as setting permissions in all the right files.

All of those steps work correctly.  But when it gets to the step:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle'
```

it hangs up there for a while.  Then I get an error that says:

```
2022-06-23 11:43:38.939 hdiutil[1168:11281] -[DIHelperProxy(Thread) waitForHelperDone] timed out waiting for helper registration
```

All of the web pages that give instructions on repairing a Sparsebundle seem to breeze right by this step as if there should be no problem with it.  But I can't get past it.

Any ideas as to what's wrong or what I can do to fix it?

Here's the full Terminal session:

```
danielkuchta@iMac ~ % cd Desktop
danielkuchta@iMac Desktop % chmod +x TimeMachineRepairScript.sh
danielkuchta@iMac Desktop % ./TimeMachineRepairScript.sh /Volumes/Transport/Mo\'s\ MacBook\ Pro\ 2018.sparsebundle
+ IMAGE='/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle'
+ '[' -z '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle' ']'
+ chflags -v nouchg '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle'
+ chflags -v nouchg '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle/token'
+ chflags -v nouchg '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle/bands'
+ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete :RecoveryBackupDeclinedDate' '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle/com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist'
Delete: Entry, ":RecoveryBackupDeclinedDate", Does Not Exist
+ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :VerificationState 0' '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle/com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist'
+ set -e
++ hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle'
++ awk '/HFS/ {print $1}'
2022-06-23 11:43:38.939 hdiutil[1168:11281] -[DIHelperProxy(Thread) waitForHelperDone] timed out waiting for helper registration
+ DEV=
+ echo '/Volumes/Transport/Mo'\''s MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle -> '
/Volumes/Transport/Mo's MacBook Pro 2018.sparsebundle -> 
+ fsck_hfs -fy -c 8gb ''
No such file or directory
Can't stat 
Can't stat : No such file or directory
danielkuchta@iMac Desktop %
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18482/repair-time-machine-sparsebundle-that-will-no-longer-mount?rq=1)?