Can a Time Machine Sparsebundle Missing All Its PLISTs (Only "bands" Remain) Be Repaired?
Somehow, I have ended up with a couple Sparsebundles that no longer have any of the usual plists in their root.  All the "bands" seem to be there, though. Time Machine will (of course) not mount them, and Disk Utility has no idea what to do with them either.  Is there any way to recover from this?

The first question is, do you need any of the data in these disk images now? If not, I suggest you put them aside in case of need, and start over. You may not be able to trust the backup device you've been using. Otherwise, you could create a new sparsebundle and just copy the top-level files to the corrupted ones. They'll still be corrupt, but now maybe you can try the steps described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18482/repair-time-machine-sparsebundle-that-will-no-longer-mount

I had looked the procedure in question 18482, but the very first step fails with the error hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory.
It isn't urgent that I recover this data, but I would like to.

I don't have any other ideas, sorry. I couldn't find any reports like yours.
